# activex stopped working for all scripts and gives "can't create control" error

Tags: autohotkey

so I tried to open an old game I made and out of nowhere there was an error. but the last time I ran it everything was fine and I hadn't modified it. the error said it was when trying to add the activex control. I removed the activex and it ran. then I quickly checked other scripts that used activex, all errors. I tested this example script:

```
Gui Add, ActiveX, w980 h640 vWB, Shell.Explorer  ; The final parameter is the name of the ActiveX component.
WB.Navigate("https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/")  ; This is specific to the web browser control.
Gui Show
```

and got this error:

```
Error: Can't create control.

         Line#
    ———> 001: Gui,Add,ActiveX,w980 h640 vWB,Shell.Explorer
         002: WB.Navigate("https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/")
         003: Gui,Show
         004: Exit
         005: Exit
         005: Exit

The current thread will exit.
```

I tried reinstalling autohotkey but the problem persists. does anyone else have this issue too?

Comment: What version of windows are you using? Is Internet Explorer still working on your system?

Comment: yes internet explorer works and the windows edition is: windows 10 enterprise and version is: 1809

Comment: Maybe try `Gui, Add, ActiveX, w980 h640 vWB, about:blank` or `Gui, Add, ActiveX, w980 h640 vWB, https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/` ?

Comment: no didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps give [Neutron.ahk](https://github.com/G33kDude/Neutron.ahk) or [Webapp.ahk](https://github.com/joedf/Webapp.ahk) a try ... If those dont work, there's likely something misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this was a decision by Microsoft, I recommend making sure ActiveX is still enabled on your system: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-activex-controls-in-internet-explorer-04774c30-617d-4de4-a028-0fe03d68b955

Comment: sorry I took so long to respond but I tried it and it didn't help. was really feeling hopeful when I ran the script but it threw the same error. I even tried restarting after the changes

Comment: Now worries, considering it happened so suddenly, it's most likely some configuration change. Maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/out-of-date-activex-control-blocking will help. Can you try to find something else that uses ActiveX(Non-AutoHotkey) and see if it works? That way you can see if it's all ActiveX or just AutoHotKey.